# How to set section titles in non-bold font while using fncychap?

Tags: fonts, section-titles

### Problem Description

I am using the Sonny style from the fncychap package in a document I am writing. I like it, but if I use just that package I obtain non-bold chapter titles and bold section (and subsection, and subsubsection...) titles which is kind of unpleasant:[image] I would like to have the section titles and so on in non bold font as well. How can I achieve this?

### MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside, DIV=9]{scrbook}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}   
\usepackage{tgadventor}     
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} 
\linespread{1.05}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}
```

Comment: It would be nice if u post a MWE.

Comment: I use the book class with `\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}` and don't make other changes, I do get bold section and subsection titles, but they're not sans serif like in your screenshot. You're either using a different document class that does that, or loading other packages that affect titles, etc. We need to know what those are, or else our "solutions" may not work. So, yes, please post a [minimal working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that).

Comment: Done, @frabjous I think this indeed depends on the fact that I am using scrbook instead of book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add three lines to your preamble: the first to have a normal font in the section title and the last two to avoid the scrbook error (`fncychap` using the old `\sf` command).

[image: c]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside, DIV=9]{scrbook}

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}   
\usepackage{tgadventor}     
\usepackage[sc]{mathpazo} 
\linespread{1.05}   
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[english]{varioref}
\usepackage[Sonny]{fncychap}

\usepackage{lipsum}

%% **************************************** added <<<<<<<<<<<<

    \addtokomafont{disposition}{\normalfont\sffamily} % avoid bold face
    \ChNameVar{\Large\sffamily} % avoid scrbook Error
    \ChTitleVar{\Large\sffamily}% avoid scrbook Error

%%**********************************************

\begin{document}

    \chapter{Measure theory}
    \lipsum[1]
    
    \section{$\sigma$--algebras and the like}   
    \lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! But, sorry, maybe I wasn't clear. I would like the titles of (sub-, subsub- and) sections to be still sans serif

Comment: @Federico R. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: `\DeclareOldFontCommand{\sf}{\normalfont\sffamily}{\mathsf}` is another way of solving the error regarding the old `\sf` command.

Comment: @ frabjous  Thank you, The OP doesn't mention the error at all. :)